# Blu Ray mkv's unable to preserve subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

I have recently ripped som blu ray discs using makemkv. I now want to change the size of the files using ffmpeg. I dont want to change the resolution, but the quality (i think it is crf as command). The problem is, that i end up with a sized down file but no subtitles. I do know that the subtitles are not text based, but i would like to know i someone knows a way to preserve the subtitles while sizing down the file.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the stream.

Issue the following command..

ffplay originalblurayfile

Look for something like this in the output.

stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480 (default)

When you re-encode your file you need to add something like -map 0:3.

See ffmpeg documentation

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map